# PDO - Fetch Assoc in a 'while' loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to echo a bit of html within a while loop. I'm getting my stuff with [PDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Development_and_community) and PDO_ASSOC.

This is what I have:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM books');
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $book_id = $row['id'];
    $book_title = $row['title'];
    $book_image = $row['image'];
    $book_amz = $row['amazon'];
    $book_desc = $row['description'];
    $book_rating = $row['rating'];
    $book_date = $row['date'];
    $book_author = $row['author'];
    $book_categorie = $row['categorie'];
    $text = "ID: ' . $book_id . '";
 }
 return $text;
```

But it gives me only one row of the table. I even tried [fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), but it gives me nothing.

Comment: Could be that the code is failing after the first iteration of the loop due to that syntax error at the end.  Check your error logs.

Comment: This `$text = 'ID: ' . $book_id . ';` should probably be `$text = 'ID: ' . $book_id;`. Not sure this is the issue but seems like a good guess

Comment: no sorry, it was just a typing error. dont have it in my code.

Comment: This is still incorrect `$text = "ID: ' . $book_id . '";` should be either `$text = "ID: '" . $book_id ."'";` or `$text = "ID: '{$book_id}'";`

Comment: this is what I have in my actual code: http://pastebin.com/02JwDwKu

Comment: Awesome! Much more helpful. Are you echoing where that return is? Is the element you see always the last element in the DB?

Comment: I'm not echoing, im only returning the $bookEcho after the while loop. and yes, its always the last.

Comment: You're overwriting your values. How would you expect it to return more than one?

Comment: I guess I forgot to say, that I have a function where its in. public function getBooks()
Edit: echoing destroys the whole page. so I used return. it makes one col-md-9 on the left site, but it should be on the right site.

Comment: So then you should return an array. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So making the assumption that the only element ever seen is the last element it is because what your are returning is being overwritten each loop. There are a few options to resolve this. The simplest is:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM books');
$stmt->execute();

$text = "";
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $book_id = $row['id'];
    $book_title = $row['title'];
    $book_image = $row['image'];
    $book_amz = $row['amazon'];
    $book_desc = $row['description'];
    $book_rating = $row['rating'];
    $book_date = $row['date'];
    $book_author = $row['author'];
    $book_categorie = $row['categorie'];

    //String concatenation of text will 
    //give you one big string at the end to return.   
    $text .= "ID: '{$book_id}'";
}
return $text;
```

However this will not work well with your real bootstrap html. You need to make sure that the columns add up right.

You will need something a bit more intuitive

Using the actual code it would look something like

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM books');
$stmt->execute();

$bookEcho = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $bookEcho[] = '<div class="col-md-3">
                   <div class="thumbnail">
                   <span>' . $book_title . '</span>
                   <img src="' . $book_image . '">
                   <div class="book-options">
                   <span>Bewertung</span><br/>
                   ' . $stars . '
                   <a href="books.php?id=' . $book_id . '" class="btn btn-read btn-block">Jetzt lesen</a>
                   </div>
                   </div>
                   </div>';
}
return $bookEcho;
```

Now in your function what ever it is you can do something like (this is not the most elegant thing I have ever written but should get the job done):

```
$cols = 4;
$colCount = 1;
foreach ($bookEcho as $book){
    if($colCount == 0){//create a row}
    echo $book;
    $coolCount++;
    if($colCount == 0){end a row}
    if($colCount == 4){ $colCount = 0;}
}
```

Comment: I would imagine so but you will run into some issues with layout using it. A string is harder to parse then the array. Although I would delay the view details until you are back in the function that kicked this off.

Comment: well for now I dont have any layout issues. I'll take this and then see what happens if I have some more entries. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're overwriting your values in your while loop. The loop is being executed once for each entry in the database, but only the last one will be returned. Instead you want to use arrays:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM books');
$stmt->execute();
$books = [];
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $book['id'] = $row['id'];
    $book['title'] = $row['title'];
    $book['image'] = $row['image'];
    $book['amz'] = $row['amazon'];
    $book['desc'] = $row['description'];
    $book['rating'] = $row['rating'];
    $book['date'] = $row['date'];
    $book['author'] = $row['author'];
    $book['categorie'] = $row['categorie'];
    $book['text'] = "ID: ' . {$book['id']} . '"; // << Not sure if this is what you actually want. If not, adjust accordingly.

    // Append the above values to the $books array
    $books[] = $book;
}
return $books;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. really appreciate it. but it gives me just "array". I removed the { } because it gaves me an error (unexpected {)

Comment: If you're trying to echo an array, that's not going to work. You will need to use one of the [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Comment: Also, it doesn't appear to be a PHP syntax error (see https://3v4l.org/USuCX). I'm not sure what you're using this string for later, but maybe that's what's causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use a *foreach*:

```
$books = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($books as $book){
    $book_id = $book['id'];
    $book_title = $book['title'];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: tried that also, gives me also only one row. and yes, I have 2 entries. thanks though

Comment: That's a structural change that doesn't address the problem: Repeatedly stomping the same variables without using them.

Comment: Apologies. My intentions were to provide a solution. Though it is a different control structure my goal was to provide some assistance.