# Reference Foreign Key PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table firmware and in it, a column category_id which is a foreign key from the table categories.
I want to fetch records from the firmware table and display them. Instead of category id it should display the category name. In normal unsafe mysql natural join was straight forward but with PDOs it does the same but duplicates the "firmware" depending on number of categories.

Say we a have a firmware called "samsung" and is in the category "repaired", And we have like 7 other categories, When i fetch the firmware samsung, my select Query will fetch it correctly but duplicate the samsung 7 times.
But if i dont natural join and just echo the category_id in the firmware table it will just be fine

Am new to PDOs..

```
   $query = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM firmware natural join categories order by firm_category asc");
   $query-> execute();

   while($row = $STH->fetch()){ ?>
      <a class="product-link" href='firm_details.php?p=<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>&amp;c=<?php echo $row['product_cat']; ?>'>
       <div class="col-md-4 mt-3">
       <div class="border p-2">
       <h6><?php  $row['cat_title'] ?></h6> //this is the foreign Key
       <h6><?php echo $row['firm_title']; ?></h6>
       </div>
       </div>
      </a>
  <?php}?>
```

Comment: PDO doesn't change the results of the query. It's just a PHP library for calling the database.

Comment: Your query doesn't select just the `samsung` firmware. It has no `WHERE` clause so it selects all firmwares along with their categories.

Comment: If you execute the same query in phpMyAdmin or the mysql command line, you should see the same results.

Comment: i think thats the problem actually

Comment: When i add where firm_category=category_id it does the trick.

Comment: You can only use `natural join` if the foreign key has the same name as the referenced column.

Comment: You should be using `INNER JOIN` instead of `NATURAL JOIN` if the column names aren't the same. And the equality check should be in `ON`.

Comment: try solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109040/pdo-fetch-assoc-in-a-while)

Comment: in your while condition `while($row = $STH->fetch()){ ?>` why u use  **$STH** variable? use **$query** like this `while($row = $query->fetch()){ ?>`.